# Resetting form fields to initial state in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I'm currently working on a form (Material-UI) that users fill in to log a set they did for an exercise. Upon submission, it will run a GraphQL mutation. As I also have login and register functionalities that share similarities, I created a form hook for these. The login and register do not need to be reset, as this is done by redirecting them to the home page. However, for the logging set functionality, I want the modal (where the form is) to close after resetting the form back to it's initial state, so that when they choose to log another set, the form does not contain the values from the previous logged set.

**Form**

```
const initialState = {
  exerciseName: "",
  weight: undefined,
  reps: undefined,
  notes: "",
};

function MyModal() {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const { onChange, onSubmit, values } = useForm(registerSet, initialState);

  const [addSet] = useMutation(ADD_SET, {
    update() {
      // need to reset form to initial state here
      handleClose();
    },
    onError(err) {
      setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    },
    variables: values,
  });

  function registerSet() {
    addSet();
  }

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      id="addSetForm"
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <TextField
        name="exerciseName"
        label="Exercise Name"
        select
        value={values.exerciseName}
        error={errors.exerciseName ? true : false}
        onChange={onChange}
      >
        <MenuItem key="Bench Press" value="Bench Press">
          Bench Press
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem key="Deadlift" value="Deadlift">
          Deadlift
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem key="Squat" value="Squat">
          Squat
        </MenuItem>
      </TextField>

      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <TextField
            name="weight"
            label="Weight"
            type="number"
            value={values.weight}
            error={errors.weight ? true : false}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <TextField
            name="reps"
            label="Reps"
            type="number"
            value={values.reps}
            error={errors.reps ? true : false}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <TextField
        name="notes"
        label="Notes (Optional)"
        type="text"
        multiline={true}
        rows="4"
        value={values.notes}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </form>
  )
}
```

**useForm Hook**

```
export const useForm = (callback, initialState = {}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]:
        event.target.type === "number"
          ? parseInt(event.target.value)
          : event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    callback();
  };

  return {
    onChange,
    onSubmit,
    passwordVisibility,
    confirmPasswordVisibility,
    values,
  };
};
```

I'm not sure how I can access `setValues` from the `useForm` hook in the `update()` handler for `useMutation` to reset the form back to it's initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:  create a resetValues() function inside your useForm hook and export it

```
const resetValues = () => {
    setValues(initialState)    
};

return {
    // ... OTHER EXPORTS
    resetValues,
  };
```

Step 2: Then use this function inside your component

```
  const { onChange, onSubmit, resetValues, values } = useForm(registerSet, initialState);

const [addSet] = useMutation(ADD_SET, {
    update() {
      resetValues(); // SEE HERE
      handleClose();
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was this simple.